# How to Map a subset of list elements to a function?

Tags: list-manipulation, map, partitions

How would you, given a list `{1, 2, 3, 4}`, apply a function `f` to `1` and `2`, then `2` and `3`, etc.?

```
{f[1,2], f[2,3], f[3,4]}
```

More generally, how do you define which parts of a list you want to pass/`Map`/`Apply` to a function that takes multiple arguments?

Comment: Thank you and a big thanks to everyone who contributed alternative solutions as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might first partition your list and then use Map as usual :

```
f[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ Partition[{1,2,3,4}, 2, 1]

(* {f[1, 2], f[2, 3], f[3, 4]} *)
```

Comment: Excellent, that works.

Comment: why is it f[#[[1]], #[[2]]] and not just f[#1,#2]?

Comment: `f[#1, #2] & @@@ Partition[{1,2,3}, 2, 1]`

Comment: @PerAlexandersson `f @@ Partition` is enough/

Comment: @Kuba you mean `f @@@ Partition[{1,2,3,4}, 2, 1]`.

Comment: @ChipHurst yes, I just focused on a changed part (was lazy).

Answer (score 25):

*Update: in version 10.2 [`BlockMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockMap.html) was added as a System context function.*

---

If the arguments are sequential there is a function [`` Developer`PartitionMap ``](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Developer/ref/PartitionMap.html) that does this directly, potentially saving considerable memory over [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html).

```
Developer`PartitionMap[f @@ # &, Range@5, 2, 1]
```

> ```
> {f[1, 2], f[2, 3], f[3, 4], f[4, 5]}
> ```

Syntax is the same as for `Partition` but with the function to map inserted as the first argument.  Notice in my use above that I needed `Apply` (short form `@@`) to pass the elements as arguments rather than a single list.

If the arguments are not sequental you can use `Part`:

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e}; 

parts = {{1, 2}, {4, 1, 3}, {5, 2}};

f @@ list[[#]] & /@ parts
```

> ```
> {f[a, b], f[d, a, c], f[e, b]}
> ```

Answer (score 18):

You can use

```
f @@@ Partition[{1,2,3,4}, 2, 1]
```

which will give

```
{f[1,2], f[2,3], f[3,4]}
```

Comment: And this one is nice and short.

Answer (score 17):

Several additional alternatives:

**`MapThread`:**

```
MapThread[g, #] &@{Most@#, Rest@#} &@{r, s, t, u, v, w}
```

> {g[r, s], g[s, t], g[t, u], g[u, v], g[v, w]}

or,

```
MapThread[g, #] &@Transpose@Partition[#, 2,1] &@{r, s, t, u, v, w}
```

> {g[r, s], g[s, t], g[t, u], g[u, v], g[v, w]}

which allows more flexibility to specify the lists to thread over, like:

```
MapThread[g, #] &@Transpose@Partition[#, 3, 2, 1] &@{r, s, t, u, v, w}
```

> {g[r, s, t], g[s, t, u], g[t, u, v], g[u, v, w]}

**`Inner`:**

With last argument set to `List` gives the same result as `MapThread`:

```
Inner[g, Sequence @@ #, List] &@Transpose@Partition[#, 2, 1] &@{r, s,t, u, v, w}
```

> {g[r, s], g[s, t], g[t, u], g[u, v], g[v, w]}

**`Thread`:**

```
Thread[g[Most@#, Rest@#]] &@{r, s, t, u, v, w};
Thread[g[Sequence @@ #]] &@({Most@#, Rest@#} &@{r, s, t, u, v, w});
Thread[g[Sequence @@ #]] &@(Transpose@Partition[#, 2, 1] &@{r, s, t,u, v, w});
```

From docs on `Thread`:

> Functions with attribute `Listable` are threaded automatically over lists.

Hence for  `Listable` functions, e.g., for `h` in the following example:

```
SetAtrributes[h, Listable];
h[Sequence @@ #] &@(Transpose@Partition[#, 2, 1] &@{r, s, t, u, v, w})
```

gives the same result as does

```
Thread[h[Sequence @@ #]] &@(Transpose@Partition[#, 2, 1] &@{r, s, t, u, v, w}).
```

Also from docs:

> `MapThread` takes the function and its arguments separately.
>
> `Thread` evaluates the whole expression before threading.

Hence, using `MapThread` is "safer" as pointed out in Mr.Wizard's comments.

**Timings:**

Test data:

```
 tsts = Table[RandomInteger[1000, 1000000], {10}];
```

Results table (apologies for not figuring out how to apply `Thread` in the following):

```
Grid[{{"method", "timing"}, 
    {HoldForm[Thread[g[Sequence @@ #]] &@(Transpose@Partition[#, 2, 1] &)], 
    Table[AbsoluteTiming[ClearSystemCache[]; 
    Thread[g[Sequence @@ #]] &@ (Transpose@Partition[#, 2, 1] &@ tsts[[i]])][[1]], 
      {i, 1, 10}] // Mean},
    {HoldForm[Thread[g[Most@#, Rest@#]] &], 
    Table[AbsoluteTiming[ClearSystemCache[]; 
    Thread[g[Most@#, Rest@#]] &@tsts[[i]]][[1]], {i, 1, 10}] //  Mean},
    {HoldForm[MapThread[g, Transpose@Partition[#, 2, 1]] &], 
    Table[AbsoluteTiming[ClearSystemCache[]; 
    MapThread[g, Transpose@Partition[#, 2, 1]] &@tsts[[i]]][[1]], {i, 1, 10}] // Mean},
    {HoldForm[MapThread[g, {Most@#, Rest@#}] &], 
    Table[AbsoluteTiming[ClearSystemCache[]; 
    MapThread[g, {Most@#, Rest@#}] &@tsts[[i]]][[1]], {i, 1, 10}] //  Mean},
    {HoldForm[Inner[g, Sequence @@ #, List] &@{Most@#, Rest@#} &], 
    Table[AbsoluteTiming[ClearSystemCache[]; 
    Inner[g,Sequence @@ #,List] &@{Most@#,Rest@#} &@tsts[[i]]][[1]], {i, 1, 10}] // Mean}, 
    {HoldForm[Inner[g, Sequence @@ #, List] &@Transpose@Partition[#, 2, 1] &], 
    Table[AbsoluteTiming[ClearSystemCache[]; 
    Inner[g, Sequence @@ #, List] &@Transpose@Partition[#, 2, 1] &@
    tsts[[i]]][[1]], {i, 1, 10}] // Mean},
    {HoldForm[Developer`PartitionMap[g @@ # &, tsts[[i]], 2, 1]], 
    Table[AbsoluteTiming[ClearSystemCache[]; 
    Developer`PartitionMap[g @@ # &, tsts[[i]], 2, 1]][[1]], {i, 1, 10}] // Mean}, 
    {HoldForm[g @@@ Partition[tsts[[i]], 2, 1]], 
    Table[AbsoluteTiming[ClearSystemCache[]; 
    g @@@ Partition[tsts[[i]], 2, 1]][[1]], {i, 1, 10}] // Mean}, 
    {HoldForm[ g @@@ Most[{tsts[[i]], RotateLeft@tsts[[i]]}\[Transpose]]], 
    Table[AbsoluteTiming[ClearSystemCache[]; 
    g @@@ Most[{tsts[[i]], RotateLeft@tsts[[i]]}\[Transpose]]][[1]], {i, 1, 10}] // Mean}, 
    {HoldForm[Fold[(Sow[g[#1, #2]]; #2) &, First@#, Rest@#] &@tsts[[i]]; // 
     Reap // Last], 
    Table[AbsoluteTiming[ClearSystemCache[]; 
     Fold[(Sow[g[#1, #2]]; #2) &, First@#, Rest@#] &@tsts[[i]]; //
      Reap // Last][[1]], {i, 1, 10}] // Mean},
    {HoldForm[g[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ Partition[tsts[[i]], 2, 1]], 
    Table[AbsoluteTiming[ClearSystemCache[]; 
     g[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ Partition[tsts[[i]], 2, 1]][[1]], {i, 1, 10}] // Mean}}, 
    Frame -> All]
```

Timing results:

[image]

Comment: Probably too specific since the OP was asking "generally" but if you expand this answer to address Listable functions and discuss the performance benefits you'll heartily earn my +1.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I like this one, and it's the type of thing I often use as I didn't know about ``Developer`Partition`` until very recently.

Comment: @rcollyer I like this one a lot too (hence: "heartily") but the answer is unfinished.  `Thread` as shown is dangerous because of evaluation order, and the most elegant an efficient possibility (with Listable functions) is neither shown nor explained.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard How is `Thread` dangerous? I don't see it. I also, don't see the answer as being incomplete. Instead, I see it as not being generalizable, e.g. what if the OP wanted to expand it to sequential, overlapping triples, instead?

Comment: @rcollyer so `f = Print; Thread[f[Most@#, Rest@#]] &@{1, 2, 3}` does what you expect and desire?  I say incomplete because the prime advantage to this method is performance, especially with Listable functions.  If kguler doesn't add that, I will.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard well with `Listable` functions neither `Thread` nor `MapThread` are necessary, e.g. `Block[{f}, SetAttributes[f, Listable]; f[Most@#, Rest@#] &@{1, 2, 3}]`. Setting `f = Print` is an interesting counter argument. I'm still parsing it. My `Listable` example doesn't function as expected with `Print`, either.

Comment: @rcollyer yes, `Most@# * Rest@#` working is my point.  The problem with `Thread` (versus MapThread) is that `f` evaluates *before* the threading operation; this is hardly safe or robust.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thank you for finally being explicit.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard & rcollyer, thank you for constructive comments/suggestions. Will put together some test results in a moment.

Comment: @kguler I look forward to upvoting your answer. :-)

Comment: @kguler I already upvoted it :). I like the timings chart. How did you do that?

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf The code for that is also provided...

Answer (score 8):

**Update:** A function `f` can be mapped to partition elements using `f` as the  ***undocumented  6th argument*** of `Partition`.

```
Partition[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 2, 1, {1, -1}, {}, f]
```

> {f[1, 2], f[2, 3], f[3, 4]}

```
Partition[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 2, 1, {1, -1}, {}, Plus]
```

> {3, 5, 7}

```
Partition[Range[10], 5, 2, None, {}, Mean[{##}] &]
```

> {3, 5, 7}

Also works with ragged partitions if `f` is defined for sequences of varying length:

```
{Partition[Range[5], 5, 2, {-1, 1}, {}],
 Partition[Range[5], 5, 2, {-1, 1}, {}, foo],
 Partition[Range[5], 5, 2, {-1, 1}, {}, Plus]} // Column // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{l}
>  \{\{1\},\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,3,4,5\},\{3,4,5\},\{5\}\} \\
>  \{\text{foo}(1),\text{foo}(1,2,3),\text{foo}(1,2,3,4,5),\text{foo}(3,4,5),\text{foo}(5)\} \\
>  \{1,6,15,12,5\} \\
> \end{array}$

---

**Original post:**

```
List @@ Partition[f[1, 2, 3, 4], 2, 1]
```

> {f[1, 2], f[2, 3], f[3, 4]}

Answer (score 7):

*Mathematica* 10 introduced [`MovingMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MovingMap.html) and [operator forms](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html):

```
MovingMap[Apply[f], Range @ 9, 2]
```

> ```
> {f[1, 2], f[2, 3], f[3, 4], f[4, 5], f[5, 6], f[6, 7], f[7, 8], f[8, 9]}
> ```

Useful information: [Mathematica periodic moving map](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64937/121)

---

In *Mathematica* 10.1 [the syntax for `MovingMap` changed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/79931/121); now you must use:

```
MovingMap[Apply[f], Range @ 9, 1]
```

> ```
> {f[1, 2], f[2, 3], f[3, 4], f[4, 5], f[5, 6], f[6, 7], f[7, 8], f[8, 9]}
> ```

Comment: There's also `ListCorrelate[{1, 1}, Range@9, {1, -1}, {}, Times, f]`

Comment: @LLlAMnYP My update is not intended to preclude that; please post that as an answer if you would like.

Comment: it's on my mind right now, as I'm reflecting on a question of mine about mapping to a subsequence of a list (generalization to multidimensional lists in a different way, than suggested before). I'm surprised, it didn't show up in the answers, as it's around since v.4, but I'm reluctant to post it, when there are now several functions in v.10 that do specifically the required thing.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I see no reason not to post it; not only are backward-compatible methods of use to many people but alternative methods can often be adapted in ways that built-ins cannot.  Incidentally `ListCorrelate` did get a mention in [my answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41917/121) to a more recent and related question.

Answer (score 6):

And yet another one:

```
list = Range[5];

f @@@ Most[{list, RotateLeft@list}\[Transpose]]

(*
==> {f[1, 2], f[2, 3], f[3, 4], f[4, 5]}
*)
```

Answer (score 5):

It's strange, that `ListCorrelate` has not been mentioned, according to the documentation, it has been around unchanged since v.4.0. It allows a one liner:

```
ListCorrelate[{1, 1}, Range@9, {1, -1}, {}, Times, f]
(* {f[1, 2], f[2, 3], f[3, 4], f[4, 5], f[5, 6], f[6, 7], f[7, 8], f[8, 9]} *)
ListConvolve[{1, 1}, Range@9, {-1, 1}, {}, Times, f]
(* {f[1, 2], f[2, 3], f[3, 4], f[4, 5], f[5, 6], f[6, 7], f[7, 8], f[8, 9]} *)
```

`ListConvolve`, as you can see, acts in a very similar manner. Their drawback is, they necessarily move along the list in steps of one. A result like

```
(* {f[1, 2, 3], f[3, 4, 5], f[5, 6, 7], f[7, 8, 9]} *)
```

does not appear to be possible(?)

Answer (score 4):

I would probably use `` Developer`PartitionMap ``, but here's an approach using `Fold`, `Reap` and `Sow` just to demonstrate the various ways of doing the same thing:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Fold[(Sow[f[#1, #2]]; #2) &, First@#, Rest@#] &@ list; // Reap // Last
(* Out[1]= {{f[1, 2], f[2, 3], f[3, 4]}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 MapIndexed[f[#1, list[[#2[[1]] + 1]]] &, Most@list]
```

or

```
f @@ RotateLeft[list, #][[1 ;; 2]] & /@ Range[0, Length[list] - 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

**1.**

`SequenceCases` - introduced in 2015 (10.1)

```
SequenceCases[list, {a_, b_} :> f[a, b], Overlaps -> True]
```

{f[1, 2], f[2, 3], f[3, 4]}

**2.**

`BlockMap` - introduced in 2015 (10.2)

```
BlockMap[Apply @ f, list, 2, 1]
```

{f[1, 2], f[2, 3], f[3, 4]}

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022 we have at our disposal the resource function called [**`ThroughOperator`**](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ThroughOperator/) that can do that. This is a development thanks to @Sjoerd Smit.

It was first suggested [**`here`**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157305/function-addition-declaring-function-as-the-total-of-a-list-of-functions/277661#277661). In the comment section under the answer @Sjoerd Smit gives motivation for its development and subsequent use for those interested. It was further used [**`in this thread`**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/256096/perform-apply-to-a-sum-of-objects/278692#278692).

The main use is if we want to apply a number of functions on a list, however, we can use it in this example as well.

```
Flatten[ResourceFunction["ThroughOperator"][{f}] /@ 
   Partition[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 2, 1]] /. f[{a_, b_}] -> f[a, b]
```

> `{f[1, 2], f[2, 3], f[3, 4]}`

Try for instance

```
Flatten[ResourceFunction["ThroughOperator"][{f, g, h, w}] /@ 
  Partition[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `MapThread` and `Construct`:

```
h[f_Symbol] := MapThread[Construct, {Array[f &, Length@#], Sequence @@ Transpose@#}] &;

h[f]@Partition[Range[4], 2, 1]

(*{f[1, 2], f[2, 3], f[3, 4]}*)

h[g]@Partition[{r, s, t, u, v, w}, 2, 1]

(*{g[r, s], g[s, t], g[t, u], g[u, v], g[v, w]}*)
```