# Evaluating a function using arguments from a sliding window over a list

Tags: list-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Map a subset of list elements to a function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4061/how-to-map-a-subset-of-list-elements-to-a-function)

I want to evaluate a function using arguments from a sliding window over a list.

As an example, lets use `Mean` as the function, window size as `3`, and the list as `Range[1, 10]`.

The results I am looking for are:

```
{ Mean[{1,2,3}], Mean[{2,3,4}], ... Mean[{8,9,10}] }
```

i.e.

```
{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

Is there something in `Mathematica` that can do this, or an improvement on the following implementations?

---

### Implementation #1

```
Slide1[f_, expr_, n_Integer] :=
  Module[{myExpr},
   myExpr = RotateRight[expr, 1];
   Nest[
    Delete[#, -1] &,
    Map[(
       myExpr = RotateLeft[myExpr, 1];
       f[myExpr[[1 ;; n]]]
       ) &, myExpr],
    n - 1]
   ];

In[]:=  Slide1[Mean, Range[1, 10], 3]
Out[]:= {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

*Rotating can not be that efficient, can it?*

```
In[]:=  AbsoluteTiming[Slide1[Mean, Range[1, 100000], 3]][[1]]
Out[]:= 3.529240
```

---

### Implementation #2

```
Slide2[f_, expr_, n_Integer] :=
 Module[{result, i},
  result = {};
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[expr] - n + 1, i++,
   AppendTo[result, f[expr[[i ;; i + n - 1]]]];
   ];
  result
  ]

In[]:=  Slide2[Mean, Range[1, 10], 3]
Out[]:= {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

*Please ... `For` and `AppendTo`*

```
In[]:=  AbsoluteTiming[Slide2[Mean, Range[1, 100000], 3]][[1]]
Out[]:= 27.811511
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4061/121  (Admittedly better written, but still a duplicate.)

Comment: I concur (the part about being a duplicate question). A "subset", "sliding window over a list", or in *Mathematica* speak, a "sublist" are the same thing.  Just did not show up in my query.

Comment: mmorris, is it OK with you if I close this question?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I like this question better, since OP showed some legwork, making this a better example of questions we'd like to see. How about closing the older one as a dupe of this instead?

Comment: @J.M. as I acknowledged I think this one is better, but I don't like the precedent it sets if we start closing *older* questions.  I think the correct action is to edit the older question to make it higher quality.

Comment: I have no problem with closing this one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a function exactly for this: `` Developer`PartitionMap ``:

```
Developer`PartitionMap[f, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 3, 1]
(* {f[{1, 2, 3}], f[{2, 3, 4}], f[{3, 4, 5}], f[{4, 5, 6}]} *)
```

The first argument to `` Developer`PartitionMap `` is the function that's being used (`f`) and all successive arguments and options are exactly the same as in `Partition`.

Comment: PartitionMap is [reportedly slow](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4065/57).

Comment: `AbsoluteTiming[Slide1[Mean, Range[1, 100000], 3]][[1]]` ==> 3.487248       `AbsoluteTiming[slide3[Mean, Range[1, 100000], 3]][[1]]` ==> 0.119232       ``AbsoluteTiming[Developer`PartitionMap[Mean, Range[1, 100000], 3, 1]][[1]]`` ==> 0.088112

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Don't see that in this case. Could be due to the use of `@@` in your linked question, but someone else might be more qualified to answer that..

Comment: On my PC I get about the same performance for `Partition` and `PartitionMap` in this situation. The link suffices to help us remember we shouldn't generalize from one data point.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries `PartitionMap` will leave a list packed, provided that you don't do something to unpack it, like use `Apply`. Generally, I've found it quite fast.

Comment: @rcollyer good to know.

Answer (score 7):

For something more general.

```
movingMap[f_, data_, r_] := 
  ListConvolve[ConstantArray[1, r], data, {-1, 1}, {}, Times, f@{##} &]

movingMap[Mean, Range[10], 3]

==> {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

Answer (score 6):

Why not just

```
slide3[f_, expr_, n_Integer] :=   f /@ Partition[expr, n, 1];
```

Comment: Exactly, why not! ;) I was unaware of the the offset. Cool thanks!

Comment: @mmorris Thanks for accepting, but I think the answer of R.M. is superior, so I'd recommend to accept that answer instead.

Comment: Agreed! Sorry need to wait longer to assign check.

Comment: Better yet, use ``Developer`PartitionMap[f, expr, n, 1]`` which tends to be faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
MovingAverage[Range[1,10],3]
```

Comment: His use of `Mean` was just an example...

Comment: While this works for the given example, it does not answer the question.