# Using MovingMap to calculate percentage changes

Tags: functions, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.1**

---

`MovingMap` (new in version 10) applies a function to discrete data over a moving window. This is very convenient for calculating the percentage change of a series.

But the error returned by the following code bothers me:

```
series = Range[5];
MovingMap[#[[2]]/#[[1]] - 1 &, series, {2}]

(* Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered. >>\*)
(* {1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4} *)
```

However, this code returns the result with no error:

```
MovingMap[f, series, {2}] /. f -> Function[#[[2]]/#[[1]] - 1]

(* {1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4} *)
```

What causes this problem?

Comment: I recommend not Accepting an answer so soon.  Someone else may have a different analysis.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard shouldn't we tag as a BUG?

Comment: @Murta Let's wait for a third experienced user to declare it a bug.

Comment: Does anyone object to tagging this one as 'fixed in 10.1.0'. I realize Mr.Wizard is pointing out additional issues in the comments, but I think this is not the same issue that was originally pointed out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### *Update*

In version 10.1 the overhang problem described below has been removed. (In the default form; with [`Method -> "Legacy"`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80092/121) the behavior below returns.)  I am therefore tagging this as a bug.

Beware that `MovingMap` syntax has [incompatibly changed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56728/121) in 10.1 as well.

---

This appears to be a bug in [`MovingMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MovingMap.html).  The function is applied beyond the left edge of the list and then the result is discarded:

```
echo[x_] := (Print[x]; x)

MovingMap[echo, Range@5, {2}]
```

> {0,1}
>
> {1,2}
>
> {2,3}
>
> {3,4}
>
> {4,5}
>
> ```
> {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}
> ```

I can see no reason to use the padding element `0` here.  Interestingly when one specifies a different padding element that first result is not discarded:

```
MovingMap[Identity, Range@5, {2}, foo]
```

> ```
> {{foo, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}
> ```

The documentation for the padding parameter is:

[image]

So *supposedly* the default is no padding, but that is not true; the default padding is `0`, and then the result is discarded.  Again:

```
MovingMap[echo, Range@5, {5}]
```

> {0,0,0,0,1}
>
> {0,0,0,1,2}
>
> {0,0,1,2,3}
>
> {0,1,2,3,4}
>
> {1,2,3,4,5}
>
> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}
> ```

There is no reason for the function (`echo`) to be applied the first four times, and in fact this directly contradicts the documentation which states that "no padding" is the default.

Also weird is this case:

```
MovingMap[echo, Range@5, {5, 2}]
```

> {0,0,0,0,1}
>
> {0,0,0,1,3}
>
> {0,0,1,3,5}
>
> ```
> MovingMap[echo, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {5, 2}]
> ```

So even though it appears that the parameters are invalid and the entire `MovingMap` expression is returned unevaluated, the `echo` function is *still* applied to three times.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO this is a Bug. You can prevent the error message in V10 using `Quiet`:

```
series = Range[5];
MovingMap[Quiet[#[[2]]/#[[1]] - 1 &], series, {2}]
```

You can also use `` Internal`PartitionMap ``, without `Quiet`:

```
Developer`PartitionMap[#[[2]]/#[[1]]-1&, Range@5, 2, 1]
```

> {1,1/2,1/3,1/4}

Post about [PartitionMap](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5467/2266)

### UPDATE

Fixed in 10.1