# Mathematica 10.1 doesn't recognize "Events" unit

Tags: units, time-series

Today's [Wolfram blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2015/05/07/spring-planting-autumn-harvest/) inspired me to play with the `TemporalData` and `MovingMap` features, and in the process of doing so, I got errors when I attempted to reproduce results from the blog post, an earlier [Stack Exchange answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79981/531), or even the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MovingMap.html):

```
MovingMap[Mean, {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, 3], 
  Subscript[x, 4], Subscript[x, 5]}, Quantity[3, "Events"]]
```

> Quantity::unkunit: Unable to interpret unit specification Events. >>
>
> MovingMap::bdwndwspc: The window specification Quantity[3,Events] is invalid. >>

In isolation:

```
Quantity[1, "Events"]
```

> Quantity::unkunit: Unable to interpret unit specification Events. >>
>
> ```
>  Quantity[1, "Events"]
> ```

FWIW, I'm running version 10.1.0 on Mac OS X (64 bit); my understanding was that the `"Events"` thing was a new feature of this version.

Comment: Weird- It *is* there with the `Ctrl+Equal` input form:

![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EVRVK.png)

but I get the same error.

Comment: @flip I can get from "1 event" to `Quantity[1, "Events"]` that way, but then sending the result to the kernel gets me the same error message.

Comment: It's most likely an issue connecting to Wolfram servers, which interpret many quantities. Adding `Events` to the list of quantities which do not require such server interaction should have been done prior to release but was overlooked. This will be fixed in an upcoming version of Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

> It's most likely an issue connecting to Wolfram servers, which interpret many quantities. Adding Events to the list of quantities which do not require such server interaction should have been done prior to release but was overlooked. This will be fixed in an upcoming version of Mathematica.
>   - Stefan R May 8 at 15:38

And it seems it was fixed. In 10.3 correct results are returned without calling Wolfram servers.