# loop execution time difference after Map operation

Tags: performance-tuning, filtering, code-review, map

I am box filtering data from a DNS simulation. When filtering the original data read from a file, this is fast. When filtering a function of these data after applying Map, it is 10 times slower. If I write the data after Map operation to a file and read in again, the filtering is fast again.

What is the difference of data after Map operation to simple numbers? How can I convert the result to numbers without writing / reading to a file?

Here is a test example:

```
    idiff = 100; jdiff = 100; kdiff = 400;
    
    cfct3Dr = Array[0.5 &, {idiff + 1, jdiff + 1, kdiff + 1}];
    
    omcc[c_, m_] = -c^(1 + m) (-1 + c^m) (1 + m) // Simplify
    
    m0 = 49/11
    
    omm0[c_] = omcc[c, m0]

  
    omDNScalc = ParallelMap[omm0[#] &, cfct3Dr, {3}];
    
    Export["omDNSdata.h5", omDNScalc];
    omDNS = Import["omDNSdata.h5", "Dataset1"];
    Delta = 32;shift = 15;niLES =4;njLES=4;nkLES=24;

    For[omDNSLES = Array[0.*# &, {niLES, njLES, nkLES}]; i = 1, 
      i <= niLES, i++, 
      For[j = 1, j <= njLES, j++, 
       For[k = 1, k <= nkLES, k++, 
        omDNSLES[[i]][[j]][[k]] = 
         Total[Total[
            Total[omDNS[[shift*(i - 1) + 1 ;; shift*(i - 1) + Delta, 
              shift*(j - 1) + 1 ;; shift*(j - 1) + Delta, 
              shift*(k - 1) + 1 ;; 
               shift*(k - 1) + Delta]]]]]/(Delta^3)]]] // AbsoluteTiming
    {0.0406014, Null}
    
    For[omDNSLEScalc = Array[0.*# &, {niLES, njLES, nkLES}]; i = 1, 
      i <= niLES, i++, 
      For[j = 1, j <= njLES, j++, 
       For[k = 1, k <= nkLES, k++, 
        omDNSLEScalc[[i]][[j]][[k]] = 
         Total[Total[
            Total[omDNScalc[[shift*(i - 1) + 1 ;; shift*(i - 1) + Delta, 
               shift*(j - 1) + 1 ;; shift*(j - 1) + Delta, 
               shift*(k - 1) + 1 ;; 
                shift*(k - 1) + Delta]]]]]/(Delta^3)]]] // AbsoluteTiming
    {1.41565, Null}
```

In this example, niLES=4,njLES=4,nkLES=27,shift=12,Delta=32, cfct3Dr and cfomDNS are 3D (100x100x340) arrays, cfct3Dr is read in from a .h5 file. The second loop need 10 times more CPU time, I could not find a difference when inspecting omDNS and omDNScalc.

Also:
Is there a more elegant way to box filter data from a bigger 3D array, maybe using Map instead
of the nested For (or Do) lists?

Comment: Please make your code self-contained. There are several undefined variables.

Comment: omm0[c] is a syntax error. It should read:  omm0[c_]. Therefore  omDNScalc will not work as expected.

Comment: Your code does not run for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgegL.png -- It looks like you're just constructing `Table[]` so that seems better that `For[]`.  Your three nested `Total[]` seem like the same as `Total[..., 3]`. These are minor compared to Daniel's remark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the difference in speed is that `omDNScalc` is not a [packed array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array).  This is a faster way to compute it that constructs a packed array:

```
omDNScalc = omm0@cfct3Dr;
```

With that change, the times are comparable and fast.

---

Alternative:  I had to experiment a little to figure out you don't sum over the whole array `omDNS` (that is, `idiff` etc. are not evenly covered by `shift` and `Delta`).  That is the reason we don’t take all of `omDNS` below.

See [`` Developer`PartitionMap ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5463/evaluating-a-function-using-arguments-from-a-sliding-window-over-a-list/5467#5467) for a useful function and [`Partition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) of which it is a generalization.  The code is no faster (except for `omm0@cfct3Dr`), but it's shorter.

```
idiff = 100; jdiff = 100; kdiff = 400;
cfct3Dr = ConstantArray[0.5, {idiff + 1, jdiff + 1, kdiff + 1}];
omcc[c_, m_] = -c^(1 + m) (-1 + c^m) (1 + m) // Simplify;
m0 = 49/11;
omm0[c_] = omcc[c, m0];
omDNScalc = omm0@cfct3Dr;
omDNS = omDNScalc;
Delta = 32; shift = 15; niLES = 4; njLES = 4; nkLES = 24;

omDNSLES = Developer`PartitionMap[
    Total[#, Infinity] &,
    omDNS[[;; -shift, ;; -shift, ;; -shift]],
    {Delta, Delta, Delta},
    {shift, shift, shift}] / Delta^3;
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps my understanding a lot!

Comment: @MichaelPfitzner You're welcome.

Comment: @MichaelPfitzner does this answer adequately address your question? If so, it is better for future users if you accept the answer by turning the checkmark green for this answer by clicking on it.

Comment: Thank you for the comment - I am a newby here and didn't know.