# Taking averages at certain intervals

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to take averages of a large two dimensional array at certain intervals. For example, for the first row, I want to take K averages of 500 values.

Here is what I am trying

```
Do[Data[[i, k]] = 
Mean[Data[[i]][[j + 1 ;; j + 500, 2 ]] ], {i, 
8}, {j, 0, 
100*5*200, 500}, {k, 1,
200} ]*)
```

Comment: Oh, I think I am redefining my matrix and using the redefined values again in all calculations.

Comment: You are right, redefining your matrix this way is inefficient and can lead to unexpected results. Have a look at `MovingAverage` in the documentation and see if that does what you need.

Comment: MovingAverage doesn't take all the elements I average over and reduce them to a single value, I think.

Comment: I see now what you are trying to do. Have a look at `Partition`. `Mean/@ Partition[data,500]` should do what you want for a vector, I think. For a 2D matrix, if what you want is a list of vectors where each vector captures the (non-overlapping) averages of 500-element sublists of each row of the original matrix, then you need: `(Mean/@Partition[#,500])/@ data`.

Answer (score 8):

Your code doesn't make sense to me.  Not only are you redefining values in `Data` mid-process, as you note, your are also extracting elements down to the third level (`Data[[i]][[j + 1 ;; j + 500, 2 ]]`) yet you say this is a "two dimensional array."

I shall assume that you want to average all elements in an *m* by *n* window, either with or without overlap.  Using this data as an example:

```
a = CharacterRange["a", "p"] ~Partition~ 4;
a // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & b & c & d \\
 e & f & g & h \\
 i & j & k & l \\
 m & n & o & p
\end{array}
\right)$

If you want to take the mean of the following $2 \times 3$ groups:

```
Partition[a, {2, 3}, 1] // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & b & c \\
 e & f & g
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 b & c & d \\
 f & g & h
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 e & f & g \\
 i & j & k
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 f & g & h \\
 j & k & l
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 i & j & k \\
 m & n & o
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 j & k & l \\
 n & o & p
\end{array}
\right)
\end{array}
\right)$

You could use:

```
Needs["Developer`"]

PartitionMap[Mean @ Flatten @ # &, a, {2, 3}, 1]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{6} (a+b+c+e+f+g) & \frac{1}{6} (b+c+d+f+g+h) \\
 \frac{1}{6} (e+f+g+i+j+k) & \frac{1}{6} (f+g+h+j+k+l) \\
 \frac{1}{6} (i+j+k+m+n+o) & \frac{1}{6} (j+k+l+n+o+p)
\end{array}
\right)$

`Partition` and `PartitionMap` have the advantage of being flexible and easy to observe, but they are also inefficient for this.  (`PartitionMap` is more memory efficient than `Partition`, but both end up adding and dividing the same elements many times.)

You can more efficiently perform this particular operation (offsets of one) using [`MovingAverage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MovingAverage.html) once in each direction:

```
Fold[MovingAverage[#\[Transpose], #2] &, a, {3, 2}] // Factor // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{6} (a+b+c+e+f+g) & \frac{1}{6} (b+c+d+f+g+h) \\
 \frac{1}{6} (e+f+g+i+j+k) & \frac{1}{6} (f+g+h+j+k+l) \\
 \frac{1}{6} (i+j+k+m+n+o) & \frac{1}{6} (j+k+l+n+o+p)
\end{array}
\right)$

Still more efficient is [`ListCorrelate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListCorrelate.html), though it is perhaps bit less intuitive:

```
ListCorrelate[ConstantArray[1/6, {2, 3}], a] // Factor // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{6} (a+b+c+e+f+g) & \frac{1}{6} (b+c+d+f+g+h) \\
 \frac{1}{6} (e+f+g+i+j+k) & \frac{1}{6} (f+g+h+j+k+l) \\
 \frac{1}{6} (i+j+k+m+n+o) & \frac{1}{6} (j+k+l+n+o+p)
\end{array}
\right)$

For different offsets `PartitionMap` is the simplest method I know of:

```
PartitionMap[Mean@Flatten@# &, a, {2, 2}] // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{4} (a+b+e+f) & \frac{1}{4} (c+d+g+h) \\
 \frac{1}{4} (i+j+m+n) & \frac{1}{4} (k+l+o+p)
\end{array}
\right)$

```
PartitionMap[Mean@Flatten@# &, a, {2, 3}, {2, 1}] // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{6} (a+b+c+e+f+g) & \frac{1}{6} (b+c+d+f+g+h) \\
 \frac{1}{6} (i+j+k+m+n+o) & \frac{1}{6} (j+k+l+n+o+p)
\end{array}
\right)$

```
PartitionMap[Mean@Flatten@# &, a, {3, 2}, {1, 2}, {-1, 1}, {}] // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & \frac{b+c}{2} & d \\
 \frac{a+e}{2} & \frac{1}{4} (b+c+f+g) & \frac{d+h}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{3} (a+e+i) & \frac{1}{6} (b+c+f+g+j+k) & \frac{1}{3} (d+h+l) \\
 \frac{1}{3} (e+i+m) & \frac{1}{6} (f+g+j+k+n+o) & \frac{1}{3} (h+l+p) \\
 \frac{i+m}{2} & \frac{1}{4} (j+k+n+o) & \frac{l+p}{2} \\
 m & \frac{n+o}{2} & p
\end{array}
\right)$

Answer (score 6):

There is also a built-in version of the 2D moving average filter called `MeanFilter`. It couldn't be simpler to use:

```
MeanFilter[data,2]
```

filters the data in the matrix by replacing every value by the mean value in its range-2 neighborhood. You can be more specific about how you want to filter by specifying {x,y} sizes separately:

```
MeanFilter[a, {2, 30}]
```

More general filters with different sizes and shape kernels can be accomplished using `ListConvolve` and/or `ListCorrelate'.