# Computing the average over the values of the boxes surrounding a box in a grid

Tags: programming

Recenty,I encounter a problem described as below:

> I have a table that owns many boxes,and each box has a sequence like 1,2,3,4,etc.In addition,every box has a value.
>
> Now I want to make the value of a box become the average of the values of boxes that arounding it.
>
> For example,
>
> `the value of box 1` become the average of `the values of box 2,11,12`,
>
> `the value of box 11` become the average of `the values of box 1,2,12,22,21`
>
> `the value of box 14` become the average of `the values of box 3,4,5,13,15,23,24,25`

```
Grid[Reverse@Partition[Range[80], 10], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

```
sequenceValue = Thread@List[Range[80], RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 80]];
Reverse@Partition[sequenceValue, 10] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

#### My trial

**Extract the sequence of the boundary of table**

```
ExtractBoundarySequence[length_, width_] := Block[
  {bottomData, topData, leftData, rightData, cornerData},
 bottomData = Range[2, length - 1];
 topData = Range[2 + (width - 1) length, width*length - 1];
 leftData = Range[1 + length, 1 + (width - 2) length, length];
 rightData = Range[2 length, (width - 1) length, length]; 
 cornerData = {1, length, 1 + (width - 1) length, width*length};
 List[cornerData, bottomData, topData, leftData, rightData]
]
```

**Extract the sequence of the innerior of table**

```
ExtractInteriorSequence[length_, width_] := Block[
{},
DeleteCases[
 Flatten@Table[{# - 1, #, # + 1} + i *length, {i, -1, 1}], #] & /@
 Flatten@Table[Range[2 + length, 2 length - 1]+(i - 1)length , {i, 1, width - 2}]
]
```

**Caculate the value of the boundary of table**

```
 CalculateBoundaryValue[SequenceValue_, length_, width_] := Block[
 {corner, bottom, top, left, right,
  cornerSequence, bottomSequence, topSequence, leftSequence, rightSequence,
 value1, value2},
 {corner, bottom, top, left, right} =ExtractBoundarySequence[length, width];
 bottomSequence = DeleteCases[
  Flatten@Table[{# - 1, #, # + 1} + i *length, {i, 0, 1}], #] & /@bottom;
 topSequence = DeleteCases[
  Flatten@Table[{# - 1, #, # + 1} + i *length, {i, -1, 0}], #] & /@top;
 leftSequence = DeleteCases[
  Flatten@Table[{#, # + 1} + i *length, {i, -1, 1}], #] & /@ left;
 rightSequence = DeleteCases[
  Flatten@Table[{# - 1, #} + i *length, {i, -1, 1}], #] & /@ right;

value1 =
 Mean /@ (Flatten[
  Map[Part[SequenceValue[[All, 2]], #] &,
   {bottomSequence, topSequence, leftSequence, 
    rightSequence}, {2}], 1]);

cornerSequence =
{
 DeleteCases[
   Flatten@Table[{#, # + 1} + i*length, {i, 0, 1}], #] &[corner[[1]]],
 DeleteCases[
   Flatten@Table[{# - 1, #} + i *length, {i, 0, 1}], #] &[corner[[2]]],
 DeleteCases[
   Flatten@Table[{#, # + 1} + i *length, {i, -1, 0}], #] &[corner[[3]]],
 DeleteCases[
   Flatten@Table[{# - 1, #} + i *length, {i, -1, 0}], #] &[corner[[4]]]
};

value2 =
  Mean /@ (Part[SequenceValue[[All, 2]], #] & /@ cornerSequence);

 Thread@List[Flatten@{corner, bottom, top, left, right}, Join[value2, value1]]
]
```

**Caculate the value of the innerior of table**

```
 CalculateInteriorValue[SequenceValue_, length_, width_] := Block[
 {interiorSequence, interiorNumber, value},
 interiorSequence =
 ExtractInteriorSequence[length, width];
 interiorNumber =
  Flatten@Table[Range[2 + length, 2 length - 1]+(i - 1)length, {i, 1, width - 2}];
 value =
     Mean /@ ((Part[SequenceValue[[All, 2]], #] &) /@ interiorSequence);
  Thread@List[interiorNumber, value]
 ]
```

**Final sequence-v-alue**

```
NewSequenceValue[SequenceValue_, length_, width_] := Block[
 {NewBoundaryData, NewInteriorData},
 NewBoundaryData =
 CalculateBoundaryValue[SequenceValue, length, width];
 NewInteriorData =
 CalculateInteriorValue[SequenceValue, length, width];
 SortBy[Join[NewBoundaryData, NewInteriorData], First]
]
```

**Using my function:**

```
Reverse@Partition[NewSequenceValue[sequenceValue, 10, 8], 10] //Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

and it can achieve the result.

However, I think my method is a little tedious, so my question: is there a better algorithm (method) to solve my problem?

Comment: Prescribe just a value (e.g. `0` or `1`) to all boxes and you are done.

Comment: @Artes,OK,I have edided my question,Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Closely related question without the complication of not counting the central value: [(28240)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28240)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bit blunt but I believe it works, it is flexible, and it should be pretty fast:

```
averages[m_?MatrixQ] :=
  With[{ker = 1 - BoxMatrix[0, 3]},
    Divide @@ (ListCorrelate[ker, #, {2, -2}, 0] & /@ {m, ConstantArray[1, Dimensions@m]})
  ]
```

`ker` is the kernel of the convolution (or correlation), in this case:

```
1 - BoxMatrix[0, 3]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}
> ```

Which represents every element in a 3x3 neighborhood except the central one.

This works on any regtangular array; applying it to a matrix of strings for illustration:

```
data = Partition[CharacterRange["a", "o"], 3];
data // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{c} \\
>  \text{d} & \text{e} & \text{f} \\
>  \text{g} & \text{h} & \text{i} \\
>  \text{j} & \text{k} & \text{l} \\
>  \text{m} & \text{n} & \text{o} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
averages[data] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \frac{1}{3} (\text{b}+\text{d}+\text{e}) & \frac{1}{5} (\text{a}+\text{c}+\text{d}+\text{e}+\text{f}) & \frac{1}{3} (\text{b}+\text{e}+\text{f}) \\
>  \frac{1}{5} (\text{a}+\text{b}+\text{e}+\text{g}+\text{h}) & \frac{1}{8} (\text{a}+\text{b}+\text{c}+\text{d}+\text{f}+\text{g}+\text{h}+\text{i}) & \frac{1}{5} (\text{b}+\text{c}+\text{e}+\text{h}+\text{i}) \\
>  \frac{1}{5} (\text{d}+\text{e}+\text{h}+\text{j}+\text{k}) & \frac{1}{8} (\text{d}+\text{e}+\text{f}+\text{g}+\text{i}+\text{j}+\text{k}+\text{l}) & \frac{1}{5} (\text{e}+\text{f}+\text{h}+\text{k}+\text{l}) \\
>  \frac{1}{5} (\text{g}+\text{h}+\text{k}+\text{m}+\text{n}) & \frac{1}{8} (\text{g}+\text{h}+\text{i}+\text{j}+\text{l}+\text{m}+\text{n}+\text{o}) & \frac{1}{5} (\text{h}+\text{i}+\text{k}+\text{n}+\text{o}) \\
>  \frac{1}{3} (\text{j}+\text{k}+\text{n}) & \frac{1}{5} (\text{j}+\text{k}+\text{l}+\text{m}+\text{o}) & \frac{1}{3} (\text{k}+\text{l}+\text{n}) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: ♦,Wow,perfect!Thanks for replacing my many lines code with your two line code.It's amazed to me.

Comment: @Tangshutao Glad I could help. :-)  Be sure to read the documentation for `ListCorrelate` so that you understand how this works.  Pay careful attention to the alignment argument (here `{2, -2}`) as it's a bit confusing at least to me, and you will need to change it if you use a kernel of a different size.

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard: very elegant. How do you copy the result of MatrixForm into the answer?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze  Thanks!  Select the output, right-click, and choose **Copy As...** > **LaTeX**.  Then paste between `$` signs in the editor, e.g. `$\{1,2\}$`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard,I thought your advanced method was only suitable for 3 $\times$ 3 matrix when you gived the answer right now. However,toady I want to understand your program and try to extend to m $\times$ n matrix, I discover that it also suitable to m \times n matrix. Although I cannot understand the two dimensions correlate(I have master the usage of `ListCorrelate` in one dimension now).Thanks!!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard,So please permit me adding this to your perfect answer.I am very happy!:)

Answer (score 4):

This answer is slightly shorter but still not very elegant.

Let m(i,j), i,j, = 1 ... n be your matrix and let us first define the number nc[] (not elegant) of cells to added in each case

```
nc[i_, j_, n_] := 
 3 /; (i == 1 && j == 1) || (i == 1 && j == n) || (i == n && 
     j == 1) || (i == n && j == n)

nc[i_, j_, n_] := 
 5 /; (i == 1 && 1 < j < n) || (i == n && 1 < j < n) || (1 < i < n && 
     j == 1) || (1 < i < n && j == n)

nc[i_, j_, n_] := 8 /; (1 < i < n && 1 < j < n)
```

Check

```
Table[nc[i, j, 3], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]

{{3, 5, 3}, {5, 8, 5}, {3, 5, 3}}
```

Now, for a given cell {i,j} define the average of all apropriate neighbouring cells:

```
s[i_, j_, n_] := 
 1/nc[i, j, n] (Sum[m[i + u, j + v], {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}] - m[i, j]) /. {m[
     0, _] -> 0, m[_, 0] -> 0, m[n + 1, _] -> 0, m[_, n + 1] -> 0}
```

Notice that 
(1) in order to keep the Sum simple we need to subtract the element m[i,j] (not elegant)
(2) we have put all elements of m beyond the "border" equal to zero

Check the result in symbolic form

```
With[{n = 3}, Table[s[i, j, n], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]]

{{(1/3)*(m[1, 2] + m[2, 1] + m[2, 2]), (1/5)*(m[1, 1] + m[1, 3] + 
     m[2, 1] + m[2, 2] + m[2, 3]), 
     (1/3)*(m[1, 2] + m[2, 2] + m[2, 3])}, {(1/5)*(m[1, 1] + 
     m[1, 2] + m[2, 2] + m[3, 1] + m[3, 2]), 
     (1/8)*(m[1, 1] + m[1, 2] + m[1, 3] + m[2, 1] + m[2, 3] + 
     m[3, 1] + m[3, 2] + m[3, 3]), 
     (1/5)*(m[1, 2] + m[1, 3] + m[2, 2] + m[3, 2] + m[3, 3])}, {(1/
     3)*(m[2, 1] + m[2, 2] + m[3, 2]), 
     (1/5)*(m[2, 1] + m[2, 2] + m[2, 3] + m[3, 1] + m[3, 3]), (1/
     3)*(m[2, 2] + m[2, 3] + m[3, 2])}}

% // MatrixForm  (* not displayed here *)
```

Now with a numerical matrix m

```
With[{n = 3}, Table[m[i, j] = Random[Integer, {1, 17}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]]

{{14, 10, 10}, {14, 2, 4}, {1, 1, 3}}

With[{n = 3}, Table[s[i, j, n], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]]

{{7, 6, 9}, {49/5, 81/8, 43/5}, {16/3, 44/5, 22/3}}

% // MatrixForm (* not displayed here *)
```

Regards,
Wolfgang

## Edit,@Wolfgang 's method just for $m_{n \times n}$

Here,editing the former method and make it applicable for $A_{m \times n}$

```
nc1[i_, j_, m_,n_] := 
 3 /; (i == 1 && j == 1) || (i == 1 && j == n) || (i == m && 
     j == 1) || (i == m && j == n)

nc1[i_, j_,m_, n_] := 
 5 /; (i == 1 && 1 < j < n) || (i == m && 1 < j < n) || (1 < i < m && 
     j == 1) || (1 < i < m && j == n)

nc1[i_, j_,m_, n_] := 8 /; (1 < i < m && 1 < j < n)
```

$\sum_{u=-1}^{1}\sum_{v=-1}^{1} A_{(i+u)(j+v)}-A_{ij}$

```
 s[i_, j_,m_,n_] := 
 1/nc[i, j,m, n] (Sum[A[i + u, j + v], {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}] - A[i, j]) /. {A[
     0, _] -> 0, A[_, 0] -> 0, A[m + 1, _] -> 0, A[_, n + 1] -> 0}
```

Example

```
Array[A, {2, 3}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
Table[s1[i, j, 2, 3], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 3}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2:** For arbitrary matrices, one can use a relabeling function like `numbering`  (from [this answer by Yu-Sung](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3589/125)) to produce a matrix with no duplicate elements, and proceed as in the original post:

```
 dataB = Partition[RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 20], 4];
 numbering[x_] := Block[{n = 0}, Replace[x, y_ :> ++n, {-1}]]; 

 dataB2 = numbering@dataB;
 dataB2 = (dataB2 /.  MapAt[Mean[Flatten[dataB][[#]]] &, 
         ComponentMeasurements[dataB2, "Neighbors"], {All, -1}]);
 Row[Grid[#, Frame -> All] & /@ {dataB, dataB2}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

---

**Original post:** If `data` does not have any duplicates:

```
data = Reverse@Partition[Range[80], 10];
data2 = (data /. MapAt[Mean, ComponentMeasurements[data, "Neighbors"], {All, -1}] // N);
Row[Grid[#, Frame -> All] & /@ {data, data2}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

**Update:** Working with symbolic matrices

```
dataA = Reverse@Partition[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 4];

dataA2 = (ArrayComponents@dataA /. MapAt[Mean[Flatten[dataA][[#]]] &, 
      ComponentMeasurements[ArrayComponents@dataA, "Neighbors"], {All, -1}]);

Row[Grid[#, Frame -> All] & /@ {dataA, dataA2}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting approach.  It seems this only works on an integer matrix however.

Comment: I don't seem to get the same results from this method as I do from mine.  I'm not sure which is correct (if either).  The inability to apply this to a symbolic matrix makes it harder to see what's going on here.

Comment: @kguler,I think `MapAt[Mean, ComponentMeasurements[data, "Neighbors"], {All, -1}]` has a mistake.

Comment: @Mr.W, right. I think it can be tweaked to work with symbolic matrices too.

Comment: @Tangshutao, do you get an error message? (It works fine form me --Version 9.0.1.0 Windows 8.0 64 bit))

Comment: @kguler,Yes,-my version is 8.0.4

Comment: @Tangshutao, can you try if `cm = ComponentMeasurements[data, "Neighbors"]; cm[[All, -1]] = Mean /@ cm[[All, -1]];
data2 = data /. cm` instead of `MapAt[...]` works for you?

Comment: @kgule,Ok,it works well!:)

Comment: I don't think these functions are designed correctly.  How can you do a `/.` on `data`?  What if there are duplicate elements?  These do not produce the output that I believe they should.  Sorry. :-(

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, just noticed your earlier comment re not getting the same results: I get the same results in version 9.0.1.0, but haven't tested this method in Version 10 yet.

Comment: I think that was just the duplicate element problem.  Your most recent code seems to work as expected.  +1 for the persistence to make it work.  However it's **painfully slow** at least with `numbering` in place: I'm measuring four orders of magnitude relative to `averages`.

Answer (score 1):

**This idea comes from @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze**

**Solving the coefficient of mean**

```
meanCoefficient[i_, j_, m_, n_] := 
 8 /; (1 < i < m && 1 < j < n)

meanCoefficient[i_, j_, m_, n_] := 
 3 /; (i == 1 && j == 1) || (i == 1 && j == n) || (i == m && 
  j == 1) || (i == m && j == n);

meanCoefficient[i_, j_, m_, n_] := 
 5 /; (i == 1 && 1 < j < n) || (i == m && 1 < j < n) || (1 < i < m &&
   j == 1) || (1 < i < m && j == n);
```

**Soling every average value of each grid**

```
MyMean[matrix_, i_, j_, m_, n_] :=
   1/meanCoefficient[i, j, m, n] ( 
     Sum[matrix[[i + 1 + u, j + 1 + v]], {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}]
     -matrix[[i + 1, j +1]])
```

**Showing result**

```
FinalResult[matrix_, m_, n_] :=
 Grid[
     Reverse@Array[MyMean[matrix, #1, #2, 8, 10] &, {m, n}],Frame -> All]
```

**Constructing the matrix**

```
finalMatrix[data_,m_, n_] := Join[
  List@Table[0, {n + 2}], Prepend[#, 0] & /@ 
  Join[Reverse@Partition[data, n], List /@ Table[0, {m}], 2], 
 List@Table[0, {n + 2}]]
```

### Example1

```
mat =finalMatrix[Range@80,8, 10];
mat//MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
N@FinalResult[Reverse@mat, 8, 10]
```

[image]

### Example2

```
data = CharacterRange["a", "i"];
finalMatrix[data, 3, 3] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
FinalResult[Reverse@finalMatrix[data, 3, 3], 3, 3]
```

[image]

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze,Thanks for your idea!!

Comment: @Tangshutao, welcome. Nice exercise. What's behind it, i.e. to which problem do you apply it? Might be a diffusion-like process ... ?

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze,I use this method to discover the differences between two sets of data.

Answer (score 1):

Recently,I know the innral function **`ArrayPad`**, and I feel it is convenient in this queastion.

```
meanCoefficient[i_, j_, row_, col_] :=
 8 /; (1 < i < row && 1 < j < col)

meanCoefficient[i_, j_, row_, col_] := 
 3 /; (i == 1 && j == 1) || (i == 1 && j == col) || (i == row && 
  j == 1) || (i == row && j == col);

meanCoefficient[i_, j_, row_, col_] := 
5 /; (i == 1 && 1 < j < col) || (i == row && 
  1 < j < col) || (1 < i < row && j == 1) || (1 < i < row && 
  j == col);
```

Computute the single element in a grid

```
ElementMean[mat_, i_, j_, row_, col_] := 
 1/meanCoefficient[i, j, row, col] *
 (Total[mat[[i ;; i + 2, j ;; j + 2]], 2] - mat[[i + 1, j + 1]])
```

#### Final function:

```
FinalResult[mat_?MatrixQ] :=
 Module[{row, col, padded},
  {row, col} = Dimensions@mat;
  padded = ArrayPad[mat, 1];
  Array[ElementMean[padded, #1, #2, row, col] &, {row, col}]
 ]
```

#### Test

```
caseSmaple = Partition[CharacterRange["a", "o"], 5];
caseSmaple // MatrixForm
```

> [image]

```
FinalResult[caseSmaple] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

> [image]

Comment: This does work but unfortunately it is very inefficient.  It seems to have about the same complexity as my code but it is several orders of magnitude slower.  For example with `big = RandomReal[99, {70, 90}];` my code `averages[big]` takes on average 0.0005 second while `FinalResult[big]` takes almost exactly two seconds.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard,OK, your solution is advanced and most optimized. In additional, I think the `main time` taken is the function `meanCoefficient`.To improve the efficiency, I should try to optimize the function `meanCoefficient`

Comment: I don't think `meanCoefficient` is a major problem.  Instead: (1) You are doing `ArrayPad[mat, 1]` for every iteration of `Array` when this should be done only once; this is the largest performance problem.  (2) There are many (uncompiled) loops which are slow, e.g. the `Sum` could be replaced with `Total[mat[[i ;; i + 2, j ;; j + 2]], 2]`, and the entire `ElementMean` should be made compilable for `Array`.  (3) This does not use incremental addition; that is to say that the sums performed for each element are independent rather that reusing the sums from the adjacent elements. (continued)

Comment: `ListCorrelate` includes this optimization.  It will become increasingly important as the size of the neighborhood increases.  I can edit your post to improve issues (1) and (2) if you will let me, but I don't feel like reimplementing `ListCorrelate` to solve (3).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard,+1, It's my pleasure that my answer can be optimized by you, `the Mathematica Expert` !

Comment: I don't know that I deserve that title, but thanks anyway.  I made my edit; please check to make sure I didn't break anything.  Also I did not make `meanCoefficient` and `ElementMean` compilable as it would require fundamentally changing the code whereas I preferred to make a few minor adjustments.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard,wow, the efficiency has improved `20 times` :-)