# List addition of certain elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list f,

```
y={{a},{b},{c},{d},{e},{f},{g},{h}...}
```

I want to sum the first 3 in this list and divide that value by 3 and append to a new list. Then repeat for the next three values. Then repeat...

So my final list will be,

```
y2={{(a+b+c)/3},{(d+e+f)/3},{(g+h+i)/3}...}
```

Comment: ``Developer`PartitionMap[Mean, y, 3]``

Comment: closely related [**28240**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28240/5478), even more general: [**4061**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4061/5478)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematica tends to involve modifying the whole list until you get the thing you want rather than looping and contracting new lists.

This is how I would think about it:

```
y = {{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}, {e}, {f}, {g}, {h}, {i}, {j}, {k}, {l}}
```

Get rid of the inside lists

```
Flatten[y]
```

> {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l}

Divide lists up uses `Partition`

```
Partition[Flatten[y],3]
```

> {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}, {j, k, l}}

I'm assuming you're adding 3 elements and diving by three to get a mean? I'll use `Mean`.

```
Mean/@Partition[Flatten[y],3]
```

> {1/3 (a + b + c), 1/3 (d + e + f), 1/3 (g + h + i), 1/3 (j + k + l)}

( This is short for `Map[Mean, Partition[Flatten[y],3]]` )

Then to get each element wrapped in a list as in your answer:

```
Transpose[{Mean/@Partition[Flatten[y],3]}]
```

> {{1/3 (a + b + c)}, {1/3 (d + e + f)}, {1/3 (g + h + i)}, {1/
>      3 (j + k + l)}}

( Alternatively `List/@Mean/@Partition[Flatten[y],3]` )

Answer (score 3):

```
y = {{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}, {e}, {f}, {g}, {h}}     
MovingAverage[y, 3][[;; ;; 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]

y = {{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}, {e}, {f}, {g}, {h}, {i}};

Mean /@ Partition[Flatten @ y, 3]
```

[image]

Comment: You've put wrong output :)

Comment: Indeed, hard to see :)