# Moving maximum function?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, data, maximum

How can I construct a moving maximum function?

For example, if I have a list of 12 values: `{ 5, 6, 9, 3, 2, 6, 7, 8, 1, 1, 4, 7 }` and I want to maximize over 3 values then the expected result would be: `{ 6, 9, 9, 9, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 4, 7, 7 }`.

Comment: I'm not clear how you got 6 as the first value of your expected result.  Shouldn't it be the maximum of `{5, 6, 9}` which is 9?

Comment: I was centering the range on the value, but you could just as well right or left shift it. In other words, in my example, the first value is the maximum of { null, 5, 6 }

Comment: @TylerDurden, why not `{Null, Null, 6}`?

Comment: Related: [(4061)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4061/121)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
test = {5, 6, 9, 3, 2, 6, 7, 8, 1, 1, 4, 7}

MaxFilter[test, 1]

(* {6, 9, 9, 9, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 4, 7, 7} *)
```

You can also use

```
Max /@ Transpose[{Rest[Append[#, 0]], #, Most[Prepend[#, 0]]}] &[yourList]
```

which is competitive with the MM MaxFilter, but will allow you to change the 'slide' (e.g.pad with zeroes, or other arbitrary 'start').

Comment: We've got a winner

Comment: +1 This function needs to be in more "See also: " sections in the documentation!

Comment: I was looking for this but there was no link around `MovingAverage` :(

Comment: Yes, WRI could do a better job there. Most of the stuff they call 'image processing' has a myriad of other uses.

Comment: This `MaxFilter` method can only handle "windows" of odd-numbered elements, since it's based on a radius, _e.g._ `MaxFilter[test, 1]` finds the maximum of 3 elements at a time, `MaxFilter[test, 2]` finds the maximum of 5 elements at a time, etc. For those wishing to use arbitrary window sizes, see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78269/6944, where I've come up with a trick for handling the even cases.

Answer (score 15):

Using the fourth and fifth arguments of `Partition` gives you exactly what you want

```
lis = {5, 6, 9, 3, 2, 6, 7, 8, 1, 1, 4, 7}
Max @@@ Partition[lis, 3, 1, {2, 2}, {}]
```

Gives:

> {6, 9, 9, 9, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 4, 7, 7}

**Update**

As Simon Wood suggested in the comment below (I also know this but on my system the difference isn't that much), `Map`ing `Max` instead of `Apply`ing it makes a difference. Also interesting, I don't notice that much difference between `` Developer`PartitionMap ``and pure `Partition` with `Map` as my timing shows with an even bigger data size, this may be a difference in version (I'm on v. 9.0.1).

**Timings**

```
lis2 = RandomInteger[10, 10^7];

(* My Solution updated with Map *)
AbsoluteTiming[Max /@ Partition[lis2, 3, 1, {2, 2}, {}]][[1]]

(* 6.203406 *)

(* My Original Solution using Apply *)

AbsoluteTiming[Max @@@ Partition[lis2, 3, 1, {2, 2}, {}]][[1]]

(* 7.750364 *)

(* Anon's Solution using PartitionMap *)

AbsoluteTiming[Developer`PartitionMap[Max, lis2, 3, 1, {2, 2}, {}]][[1]]

(* 5.675949 *)

(* Kuba's ListConvolve (You can also use ListCorrelate) *)

AbsoluteTiming[ListConvolve[{1, 1, 1}, lis2, {2, -2}, {}, Times, Max]][[1]]

(* 12.078693 *)

(* rasher's winner using MaxFilter *)

AbsoluteTiming[MaxFilter[lis2, 1]][[1]]

(* 0.640655 *)

(* rasher's second equally fast solution using Transpose and co. *)

AbsoluteTiming[Max /@ Transpose[{Rest[Append[#, 0]], #, Most[Prepend[#, 0]]}] &[lis2]][[1]]

(* 0.765662 *)
```

Clearly, rasher's methods are winners.

Comment: You're a better partitioner than I sir!

Comment: @CodieCodeMonkey. Thank you sir! `Partition` is a very powerful too. I spent quite a while exploring how to use it. Sal Mangano also does a good job on his website explaining it.

Comment: As a curiosity I might add that I learned about Developer`PartitionMap, which is undocumented, that I use from Sal Manganos' Mathematica Cookbook. I've since seen it on here. But he implements moving average, which is the same kind of operation, not with PartitionMap but with `ListConvolve` thus making him a possible reference for all three methods hehe :)

Comment: @Anon, I also learned about ``Developer`PartitionMap`` from Sal's book

Comment: Nice! May I ask how you wrote Developer`PartitionMap highlighted as code, I couldn't make it work?

Comment: @Anon I used double (``) at the beginning and end

Comment: @Anon in comments (only, AFAICT), you can also escape the \` if you want it at the beginning or end of a code string, or by itself. To do this, add a backslash before it: \`\\`\` gives `\``.

Comment: For long lists it's probably slightly quicker to map `Max` rather than `Apply` it.

Comment: @SimonWoods, I agree. When I posted my answer I didn't realize it was going to be a timing contest. I'll update mine with `Map` and post my timings. Interestingly in V. 9.0.1 I don't get Anon's huge difference.

Comment: @RunnyKine Wait, I'll update mine, didn't realize there was anything wrong before you said this. I know many who do timings repeat several times and take the average. I now know why...

Comment: List manipulation questions almost invariably end up as a timing contest because there are so many ways to accomplish the same thing :-)

Comment: 'annihilates'? The second method I posted is pretty much the same speed on the little box I timed it on, with the benefit (if needed) of flexibility in setting start-element conditions. Curious how it would time on your setup. Thanks for benchmarking them!

Comment: @rasher, I completely forgot about your second method. I'll update my timings now.

Answer (score 13):

Another option is `` Developer`PartitionMap ``. In RunnyKine's solution we first partition the list and sweep through it to add `Max` to every element. With `` Developer`PartitionMap `` we can do both at the same time, which is faster.

Here's a table for reference. My first table was incorrect and I apologize for that, it was an honest mistake which I am not sure how it happened:

```
lis = RandomInteger[10, 10^6];

AbsoluteTiming[Developer`PartitionMap[Max, lis, 3, 1, {2, 2}, {}]][[1]]
(* Out: 0.578836 *)

(* RunnyKine's solution: *)
AbsoluteTiming[Max /@ Partition[lis, 3, 1, {2, 2}, {}]][[1]]
(* Out: 0.698822 *)

(* Kuba's solution: *)
AbsoluteTiming[ListConvolve[{1, 1, 1}, lis, {2, -2}, {}, Times, Max]][[1]]
(* Out: 1.294132 *)
```

Did not see this coming! Rasher's method that he just posted is way faster:

```
AbsoluteTiming[MaxFilter[lis, 1]][[1]]
(* Out: 0.070911 *)
```

Comment: Faster and less memory hungry

Comment: ;-) - one of the seldom used but sometimes really useful functions!

Answer (score 10):

Just a different method:

```
lis = {5, 6, 9, 3, 2, 6, 7, 8, 1, 1, 4, 7};

ListConvolve[{1, 1, 1}, lis, {2, -2}, {}, Times, Max]
```

> ```
> {6, 9, 9, 9, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 4, 7, 7}
> ```

Comment: A modification: `ListConvolve[{1, 1, 1}, li, {2, -2}, -Infinity, #2 &, Max]`, which unfortunately isn't any faster (as opposed to what I wrote previously in a comment! - I compared with different sizes of data by mistake)

Comment: @Aky Indeed it isn't but I find you comment useful anyway :)

Answer (score 6):

[Dilation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dilation.html) produces the same output as `MaxFilter` and has comparable speed.

```
test = {5, 6, 9, 3, 2, 6, 7, 8, 1, 1, 4, 7};

Dilation[test, 1]
(* {6, 9, 9, 9, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 4, 7, 7} *)
```

It also has a `Padding` option which may be convenient:

```
Dilation[test, 1, Padding -> 10]
(* {10, 9, 9, 9, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 4, 7, 10} *)
Dilation[test, 1, Padding -> "Periodic"]
(* {7, 9, 9, 9, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 4, 7, 7} *)
```

Using RunnyKine's test setup we get speeds comparable to rasher's two methods:

```
lis2 = RandomInteger[10, 10^7];

AbsoluteTiming[Dilation[lis2, 1]][[1]]
(* 0.754053 *)
AbsoluteTiming[MaxFilter[lis2, 1]][[1]]
(* 0.678272 *)
AbsoluteTiming[Max /@ Transpose[{Rest[Append[#, 0]], #, 
  Most[Prepend[#, 0]]}] &[lis2]][[1]]
(* 0.786325 *)
```

Comment: Not quite the same results - you're kind of forced to check ends and pad or jump through other hoops (e.g. where there's a negative on one or both ends)... and as span of what's to be maxed increases, you need to check for more and more cases like that... but neat answer, so +1 and stay tuned for more.