# Mathematica periodic moving map

Tags: map

I am pleased to have MovingMap in Mathematica 10. But, today, I encountered the problem that needs MovingMap with a periodic boundary condition.

To be specific, Consider the following example.

```
MovingMap[ f, Range[3], {2} ]
```

will gives the result `{f[{1, 2}], f[{2, 3}], f[{3, 4}]}`. 
However, what I want to get is `{f[{1, 2}], f[{2, 3}], f[{3, 4}], f[{4,1}]}`.

One of the easiest and straightforward way would be calculating the last one and then join the lists together. But I want to know if there is more elegant way to do it. (I checked the optional arguments of `MovingMap` but I couldn't find a solution.)

Comment: Use `Map` with `Partition`: `f /@ Partition[Range[4], 2, 1, {1, 1}]` gives `{f[{1, 2}], f[{2, 3}], f[{3, 4}], f[{4, 1}]}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`"Reflected"` padding works as desired but `"Periodic"` padding is missed. There is corresponding definition for `"Reflected"`

```
RandomProcesses`TemporalDataUtilitiesDump`toCannonicalPadding[
  RandomProcesses`TemporalDataUtilitiesDump`td_, "Reflected", 
  RandomProcesses`TemporalDataUtilitiesDump`w_, 
  RandomProcesses`TemporalDataUtilitiesDump`Caller_] := 
 Reverse[Rest[
   TemporalData`Utilities`TDResample[
     RandomProcesses`TemporalDataUtilitiesDump`td,
     RandomProcesses`TemporalDataUtilitiesDump`w, {}, 
     RandomProcesses`TemporalDataUtilitiesDump`Caller]["Values"]]]
```

So we can add a similar definition for `"Periodic"`

```
RandomProcesses`TemporalDataUtilitiesDump`toCannonicalPadding[
  RandomProcesses`TemporalDataUtilitiesDump`td_, "Periodic", 
  RandomProcesses`TemporalDataUtilitiesDump`w_, 
  RandomProcesses`TemporalDataUtilitiesDump`Caller_] := 
 TemporalData`Utilities`TDResample[
   RandomProcesses`TemporalDataUtilitiesDump`td, 
   RandomProcesses`TemporalDataUtilitiesDump`w, {}, 
   RandomProcesses`TemporalDataUtilitiesDump`Caller]["Values"]
```

Verification:

```
MovingMap[f, Range[3], {2}, "Periodic"]
(* {f[{3, 1}], f[{1, 2}], f[{2, 3}]} *)
```

Comment: You can get this result with `MovingMap[f, Range[3], {2}, Range[3]]`. With either approach a `RotateLeft` is required to put in order that OP requested.

Answer (score 9):

Here is one way:

```
movingMapCircular[f_, l_List] := MapThread[f@* List, {l, RotateLeft[l]}];
```

For example:

```
movingMapCircular[f, {1, 2, 3, 4}]

(* {f[{1, 2}], f[{2, 3}], f[{3, 4}], f[{4, 1}]} *)
```

A generalization of this approach for arbitrary window size may look like:

```
ClearAll[movingMapCircular];
movingMapCircular[f_, l_List, {n_Integer}] :=
  MapThread[
    f@* List,
    MapThread[RotateLeft, {ConstantArray[l, n], Range[0, n - 1]}]
  ];
```

for example:

```
movingMapCircular[f, Range[5], {3}]

(* {f[{1, 2, 3}], f[{2, 3, 4}], f[{3, 4, 5}], f[{4, 5, 1}], f[{5, 1, 2}]} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

With versions 10.4.1 and 11.0.1 `"Periodic"` works:

```
MovingMap[f, Range[5], 1, "Periodic"]
MovingMap[f, Range[5], {1, Left}, "Periodic"]
MovingMap[f, Range[5], 2, "Periodic"]
MovingMap[f, Range[5], {2, Center}, "Periodic"]
```

> ```
> {f[{5, 1}], f[{1, 2}], f[{2, 3}], f[{3, 4}], f[{4, 5}]}
>
> {f[{1, 2}], f[{2, 3}], f[{3, 4}], f[{4, 5}], f[{5, 1}]}
>
> {f[{4, 5, 1}], f[{5, 1, 2}], f[{1, 2, 3}], f[{2, 3, 4}], f[{3, 4, 5}]}
>
> {f[{5, 1, 2}], f[{1, 2, 3}], f[{2, 3, 4}], f[{3, 4, 5}], f[{4, 5, 1}]}
> ```

But `MovingMap` is still one order of magnitude slower than `Map` + `Partition`:

```
ClearSystemCache[]
m1 = MovingMap[f, Range[10^6], {2, Center}, "Periodic"]; // RepeatedTiming
ClearSystemCache[]
m2 = f /@ Partition[ArrayPad[Range[10^6], {1, 1}, "Periodic"], 3, 1]; // RepeatedTiming
ClearSystemCache[]
m3 = f /@ Partition[Range[10^6], 3, 1, {2, 2}]; // RepeatedTiming
ClearSystemCache[]
m4 = Developer`PartitionMap[f, Range[10^6], 3, 1, {2, 2}]; // RepeatedTiming
m1 === m2 === m3 === m4
```

> ```
> {6.60, Null}
>
> {0.950, Null}
>
> {0.987, Null}
>
> {1.07, Null}
>
> True
> ```