# Linear combination of successive elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Say I have a list $E$ and want to build a list $F$ with the entries $F_j=E_j-2E_{j-1}+E_{j-2}$. I know that this happens to be achievable by iterating the function `Differences`      , but is there a way how to generalize this to different linear combinations?

Comment: Related: [(4061)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4061/121)

Comment: This looks like a finite difference stencil. See detailed docs for NDSolve for higher order schemes ...if that is what you mean by different linear combinations

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ListConvolve[{1, -2, 1}, mylist]
```

Example

```
mylist = RandomInteger[10, {10}]
```

(* {5, 4, 10, 1, 7, 1, 7, 0, 8, 4} *)

```
ListConvolve[{1, -2, 1}, mylist]
```

(* {7, -15, 15, -12, 12, -13, 15, -12} *)

Comment: Perhaps an easier to follow example: `mylist = f/@ Range@10; ListConvolve[{1, -2, 1}, mylist]`

Comment: Yes.  Quite clear.

Answer (score 1):

**Using `BlockMap`:**

```
Clear[arr, e, f];
arr = Array[e, 10]
f = BlockMap[Apply[#3 - 2 #2 + #1 &], arr, 3, 1]
```

> {e[1] - 2 e[2] + e[3], e[2] - 2 e[3] + e[4], e[3] - 2 e[4] + e[5],
> e[4] - 2 e[5] + e[6], e[5] - 2 e[6] + e[7], e[6] - 2 e[7] + e[8],
> e[7] - 2 e[8] + e[9], e[8] - 2 e[9] + e[10]}

Answer (score 1):

Using `Table`:

```
arr = Array[e, 10];

Table[#[[i + 2]] - 2 #[[i + 1]] + #[[i]], {i, 1, Length[#] - 2}] &@arr

(*{e[1] - 2 e[2] + e[3], e[2] - 2 e[3] + e[4], e[3] - 2 e[4] + e[5], 
  e[4] - 2 e[5] + e[6], e[5] - 2 e[6] + e[7], e[6] - 2 e[7] + e[8], 
  e[7] - 2 e[8] + e[9], e[8] - 2 e[9] + e[10]}*)
```