# Find rank of the row nearest to random variable

Tags: matrix, probability-or-statistics

I have following code

```
dist[a_, b_] = WeibullDistribution[a, b];
data = Table[
  j = Table[i = RandomVariate[dist[2, 1], {3, 3}], {i, 1, 4}], {j, 1, 
   3}]
```

above code generates 3*3 matrix four times and repeat all process three times. Next I want to grab the nearest value in each row as compare to random number with its rank (Minimum to maximum) in each row

```
data1 = Table[
  Table[Table[
    Nearest[data[[k, i, j]], RandomVariate[dist[2, 1]]], {j, 1, 
     3}], {i, 1, 4}], {k, 1, 3}]
```

Above code grabs the nearest value of the random number in each row. But I have no idea how to separate first, second and third ranked values. e.g in data1 we get total 36 values, some of them first ranked, some second and remaining third ranked.

Comment: you don't need to nest `Table` like that; you can write eg `Table[{i,j,k},{i,1,2},{j,1,2},{k,1,2}]`; your iteration compares each row in every matrix with a randomly generated number; `Nearest` returns a single number from each row: the one nearest to the random number generated each time; what do you mean "*I have no idea how to separate first, second and third ranked values*"?

Comment: I have also observed the rank of the selected observation. There are three ranks in a row, so I need to know which one are first, second and third ranked values

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** If the same random seed is used, the following matches the results in OP's self-answer:

```
SeedRandom[1]
dim = 3; mats = 4; n = 3;
data = RandomVariate[dist[2, 1], {n, mats, dim, dim}];
databt = RandomVariate[dist[2, 1], {n, mats, dim}];


TeXForm[data]
```

> $$\tiny\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0.449043 & 1.48137 & 0.48613 \\
>  1.2932 & 1.19225 & 1.64987 \\
>  0.782326 & 1.21024 & 0.962458 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0.596656 & 1.24579 & 0.538028 \\
>  0.927759 & 1.18168 & 0.151963 \\
>  0.438377 & 0.278683 & 0.740327 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1.10816 & 1.25299 & 0.737502 \\
>  1.43155 & 1.08755 & 0.582804 \\
>  0.969597 & 0.445523 & 1.05965 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0.72258 & 0.810115 & 1.33333 \\
>  0.865783 & 0.462852 & 2.10634 \\
>  1.07203 & 0.485768 & 2.10349 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0.96868 & 0.882563 & 0.882634 \\
>  0.56402 & 0.484774 & 1.15524 \\
>  1.10104 & 0.901214 & 1.70141 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0.85481 & 0.550826 & 1.26273 \\
>  0.779351 & 0.758341 & 0.51416 \\
>  0.164397 & 1.29721 & 0.815494 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1.05785 & 1.26957 & 0.784296 \\
>  0.876061 & 1.13112 & 0.775078 \\
>  0.750277 & 0.782584 & 0.38401 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0.636682 & 1.13854 & 0.666643 \\
>  0.596915 & 1.05141 & 1.80751 \\
>  1.5429 & 0.625666 & 0.935543 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0.182974 & 0.560791 & 1.04689 \\
>  0.426948 & 0.308514 & 0.603491 \\
>  1.26573 & 0.401616 & 0.632274 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1.22939 & 0.869507 & 1.23884 \\
>  0.738202 & 0.753391 & 2.00657 \\
>  0.240648 & 0.722363 & 1.55349 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1.35294 & 0.717737 & 1.27567 \\
>  0.806159 & 1.00854 & 1.46412 \\
>  1.40222 & 1.20532 & 0.663839 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1.81562 & 0.775681 & 1.38224 \\
>  0.843356 & 1.44941 & 0.452277 \\
>  0.79226 & 1.07275 & 0.771253 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

```
nearestvalueF = Map[Nearest, data, {3}];
nearestvalues = MapThread[#[#2][[1]] &, {nearestvalueF, databt}, 3];
TeXForm[nearestvalues]
```

> $$\tiny\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  \{0.449043,1.19225,0.782326\} & \{0.538028,1.18168,0.740327\} & \{0.737502,1.08755,1.05965\} &
>    \{1.33333,0.865783,0.485768\} \\
>  \{0.96868,0.484774,0.901214\} & \{0.85481,0.51416,0.164397\} & \{1.26957,1.13112,0.38401\} &
>    \{0.636682,1.05141,0.935543\} \\
>  \{0.182974,0.426948,1.26573\} & \{1.22939,0.738202,0.240648\} & \{0.717737,1.46412,1.20532\} &
>    \{1.38224,0.452277,0.771253\} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

```
rankofnearestF = Map[Nearest[Sort[#] -> Automatic] &, data, {3}];
ranksofnearest = MapThread[#[#2][[1]] &, {rankofnearestF, databt}, 3];
TeXForm[ranksofnearest]
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  \{1,1,1\} & \{1,3,3\} & \{1,2,3\} & \{3,2,1\} \\
>  \{3,1,1\} & \{2,1,1\} & \{3,3,1\} & \{1,2,2\} \\
>  \{1,2,3\} & \{2,1,1\} & \{1,3,2\} & \{2,1,1\} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

```
combined = MapThread[List, {nearestvalues, ranksofnearest}, 3];
```

With this result we can match  `rmin`, `rmedian` and `rmax` in OP's self-answer is preceded with `SeedRandom[1]`:

```
Sort@Flatten@Pick[combined[[All, All, All, 1]], combined[[All, All, All, 2]], 1] 
  == rmin
```

> True

```
Sort@Flatten@Pick[combined[[All, All, All, 1]], combined[[All, All, All, 2]], 2] 
  == rmedian
```

> True

```
Sort@Flatten@ Pick[combined[[All, All, All, 1]], combined[[All, All, All, 2]], 3] 
   == rmax
```

> True

```
Sort @ Tally @ Flatten @ ranksofnearest
```

> {{1, 18}, {2, 9}, {3, 9}}

```
Length /@ {rmin, rmedian, rmax}
```

> {18, 9, 9}

```
Legended[MatrixForm[Map[Style[#[[1]], (#[[2]] /. {1 -> Red, 2 -> Green, 3 -> Blue})] &, 
    combined, {-2}]], 
 Placed[Column[Style @@@ Transpose[{{"rank", "first", "second", "third"}, 
   {{Black, 16}, Red, Green, Blue}}], Dividers -> {False, 2 -> True}], Right]]
```

[image]

**Note:** In versions 10+, you can get the nearest values and their ranks using a single `Nearest` function:

```
nearestValuesAndRanksF = Map[Nearest[Sort[#] -> {"Element","Index"}] &, data, {3}];
combined2 = MapThread[#[#2][[1]] &, {nearestValuesAndRanksF, databt}, 3];
combined2 == combined
```

> True

---

**Original answer:**

```
data1 = Table[Table[Table[
  Nearest[Sort@data[[k, i, j]] -> Automatic, RandomVariate[dist[2, 1]]][[1]], 
 {j, 1, 3}], {i, 1, 4}], {k, 1, 3}];

TeXForm @ data1
```

> $$, \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  \{1,1,2\} & \{1,1,1\} & \{3,3,1\} & \{1,2,3\} \\
>  \{1,2,3\} & \{2,3,2\} & \{1,1,2\} & \{3,3,3\} \\
>  \{1,3,2\} & \{3,3,2\} & \{2,1,3\} & \{3,1,3\} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

In versions 10+, you can also use `"Index"` instead of `Automatic` in the first argument of `Nearest`.

**Update:** a cleaner version  without nested `Table`s:

```
datab = RandomVariate[dist[2, 1], {3, 4, 3, 3}];
nfs = Map[Nearest[Sort[#] -> Automatic] &, data, {3}];
databt = RandomVariate[dist[2, 1], {3, 4, 3}];
MapThread[#[#2][[1]] &, {nfs, databt}, 3]// TeXForm
```

> $$ \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  \{1,1,3\} & \{1,1,1\} & \{3,2,3\} & \{1,2,3\} \\
>  \{1,3,3\} & \{1,2,2\} & \{1,1,2\} & \{2,3,3\} \\
>  \{2,3,3\} & \{3,3,1\} & \{2,3,3\} & \{2,2,2\} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

Comment: I need ranked observations, not their ranked. Please see my answer.

Comment: @SAAN, please see the update.

Comment: Nice answer, 1+

Answer (score 1):

**update**

*side-note*: Coincidentally, I found out about this use of `Partition` from [*here*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4061/how-to-map-a-subset-of-list-elements-to-a-function/151657#151657); kudos to @kglr.

```
With[{dim = 3, mats = 4, n = 3},
 With[{a = 2, b = 1},
  BlockRandom[
   With[{rands = RandomVariate[WeibullDistribution[a, b], mats n dim^2]},
    Grid[
     Block[{f},
       (* f operates on matrix rows *)
       f = With[{row = {##}, rand = RandomVariate[WeibullDistribution[a, b]]},
             (* Nearest *)
             With[{near = First[Nearest[row, rand]]},
               (* rank of nearest *)
               {First[Position[Sort[row], near]], near}
              ]
            ] &;
       (* use Partition to construct the data and apply f on each row *) 
       With[{data = Partition[Partition[Partition[rands, dim, dim, {1, 1}, {}, f], dim], mats]},
         Apply[
           (* prepare output - operate on grouped data *)
           (* transpose grouped data, get an instance of the rank and the entries-prettify the entries *)    
           Through[{#[[1, 1]] &, Grid[Partition[#[[-1]], 4, 4, {1, 1}, {}]] &}[Transpose[{##}]]] &,
           (* flatten output from f, sort by rank and then group by rank *)
           GatherBy[Sort[Flatten[data, 2]], First], {1}]
        ]
       ] // Prepend[#, {Rank, Entries}] &, Alignment -> {Left, Top}]
    ], RandomSeeding -> 1]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

*Below this line is the original version of this answer.*

---

We will first generate all the random numbers that are needed for the matrices and then we are going to test the rows using `Nearest`.

```
(* dim is the dimension of the square matrix *)
(* mats stands for the number of matrices to use *)
(* n equals the number of repetitions *)
With[{dim = 3, mats = 4, n = 3},
  (* a, b are the parameters for the Weibull distribution *)
  With[{a = 2, b = 1},
    (* for reproducibility *)
    BlockRandom[
      (* generate random numbers *)
      With[{rands = RandomVariate[WeibullDistribution[a, b], mats n dim^2]},
        (* partition the random numbers to the appropriate dimensions *)
        With[{data = Partition[Partition[Partition[rands, dim, dim], dim], mats]},
          (* first apply Nearest on the rows of each matrix and then sort the output *)
          Apply[
            (* ...then *) 
            Sort@MapIndexed[{First[#1], Row[{Row, , First[#2]}]} &, {##}] &, 
            (* first *)  
            Apply[Nearest[{##}, RandomVariate[WeibullDistribution[a, b]]] &, data, {3}], {2}]]],RandomSeeding->1234659]]]
```

If we evaluate the code block above, we should get

> ```
> {{{{1.15798, Row[{Row,  , 3}]}, {1.21961, Row[{Row,  , 1}]}, {1.42817,
> Row[{Row,  , 2}]}}, {{0.469189, Row[{Row,  , 2}]}, {0.650485, 
> Row[{Row,  , 3}]}, {0.848214, Row[{Row,  , 1}]}}, {{0.507585, 
> Row[{Row,  , 1}]}, {0.585714, Row[{Row,  , 2}]}, {0.93049, 
> Row[{Row,  , 3}]}}, {{0.507753, Row[{Row,  , 2}]}, {0.733691, 
> Row[{Row,  , 1}]}, {1.27576, Row[{Row,  , 3}]}}}, {{{0.465733, 
> Row[{Row,  , 1}]}, {0.561231, Row[{Row,  , 3}]}, {1.16744, 
> Row[{Row,  , 2}]}}, {{0.498253, Row[{Row,  , 3}]}, {0.522801, 
> Row[{Row,  , 1}]}, {1.18593, Row[{Row,  , 2}]}}, {{0.59206, 
> Row[{Row,  , 3}]}, {0.8312, Row[{Row,  , 1}]}, {0.923146, 
> Row[{Row,  , 2}]}}, {{0.460762, Row[{Row,  , 2}]}, {0.745601, 
> Row[{Row,  , 3}]}, {0.753253, Row[{Row,  , 1}]}}}, {{{0.377382, 
> Row[{Row,  , 2}]}, {0.485119, Row[{Row,  , 3}]}, {0.704786, 
> Row[{Row,  , 1}]}}, {{0.379037, Row[{Row,  , 2}]}, {0.741862, 
> Row[{Row,  , 3}]}, {0.809665, Row[{Row,  , 1}]}}, {{0.998331, 
> Row[{Row,  , 2}]}, {1.07737, Row[{Row,  , 3}]}, {1.29412, 
> Row[{Row,  , 1}]}}, {{0.589772, Row[{Row,  , 1}]}, {0.616004, 
> Row[{Row,  , 2}]}, {1.25385, Row[{Row,  , 3}]}}}}
> ```

Please note that the `Row[{Row,,#}]` entries are there to designate the original row. For example, in the last row above, the nearest entry of the first row is the smallest, followed by the nearest entry of the second row and finally that is followed by the nearest entry in the third row.

Answer (score 0):

My try is here: I want the first, second and third ranked values selected in each row. As I have 36 rows, so finally I want 36 observations with their ranked. 
I proceed as
(*Generate 3*3 four time and repeat it three times a matrix follows Weibull Distribution*)

```
dist[a_, b_] = WeibullDistribution[a, b];
data = RandomVariate[dist[2, 1], {3, 4, 3, 3}];
```

(*Next select nearest value of each row as compare to random number*)

```
    data1 = Flatten[
  Table[Table[
    Table[Nearest[data[[k, j, i]], RandomVariate[dist[2, 1]]], {i, 1, 
      3}], {j, 1, 4}], {k, 1, 3}]];
```

(*Next separate the each ranked observation in data*)

```
    data2 = Flatten[
  Table[Table[
    Table[RankedMin[data[[k, i, j]], 1], {j, 1, 3}], {i, 1, 4}], {k, 
    1, 3}]];
data3 = Flatten[
  Table[Table[
    Table[RankedMin[data[[k, i, j]], 2], {j, 1, 3}], {i, 1, 4}], {k, 
    1, 3}]];
data4 = Flatten[
  Table[Table[
    Table[RankedMin[data[[k, i, j]], 3], {j, 1, 3}], {i, 1, 4}], {k, 
    1, 3}]];
```

(*Now compare each ranked observation with the selected observation(with nearest command)*)

```
rmin = Intersection[data1, data2]
rmedian = Intersection[data1, data3]
rmax = Intersection[data1, data4]
```

(*Sum of length size should be 36*)

```
Length[rmin] + Length[rmedian] + Length[rmax]
```

Thats it. But next I need more general code for any size, Updated versions are welcome.

Comment: thank you for the update; technically it should have been appended to the question as a clarification of what you are trying to achieve-unless you actually intended to answer your own question. For future reference, try and use `Seed` or `BlockRandom` when dealing with random numbers; it makes the code reproducible and easier for other users to compare output/intermediate results; also, see @kglr for an idiomatic use of `RandomVariate` that would have made it easier *not* to use nested `Table`'s

Comment: although it's clearer now what you intend to do with your code, it is still unclear to me what the output of the code should be; please clarify. Finally, it would be welcomed if you could provide a hint about the expected range of inputs

Comment: @user42582 Thanks for your comments, I need output in two columns. First column contain "rank" and second "observations". e.g in first row of that table we should have first rank in first column and all first ranked observation in second column of first row {1,{0.22,0.36,0.56...}} or {rank,{observations}}. And about expected range of inputs Matrix size maximum 10*10 but whole process at least repeat 10,000 times.