# How to apply a function to successive overlapping list elements?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of elements and I would like to create a new list by applying a function to successive overlapping pairs from the original list.

Specifically, I am trying to compute the Pythagorean sum of each pair. So, if the original list is {$a,b,c,d,...$} I want {$\sqrt{a^2+b^2},\sqrt{b^2+c^2},\sqrt{c^2+d^2},...$}

Since this is similar to the built-in `Differences` function, (which turns the original list into {$b-a,c-b,d-c,...$}), I expected to find a built-in function along the lines of `BuiltIn[f,{a,b,c,d,...},options]` where `f` is defined by the user. But alas, my search has been fruitless...

Thanks in advance!

-----------EDIT-----------

Right after posting this, I came up with

```
Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2] & @@@ Subsequences[#, {2}] &@{a, b, c, d}
```

which does the trick. I was going to update that here, but you all already came through with your answers, so I'll try those as well. Thanks!

Comment: `Norm /@ Partition[yourList, 2, 1]`?

Comment: Perhaps something like `Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2] & @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1]`?

Comment: Relevant answers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4061/134), in particular `PartitionMap`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`BlockMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockMap.html) + [`Norm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Norm%60.html)

```
BlockMap[Norm, {a, b, c, d, e}, 2, 1]
```

> ```
> {Sqrt[Abs[a]^2 + Abs[b]^2], Sqrt[Abs[b]^2 + Abs[c]^2], 
>   Sqrt[Abs[c]^2 + Abs[d]^2], Sqrt[Abs[d]^2 + Abs[e]^2]}
> ```

```
TeXForm @ Simplify[%, Thread[{a, b, c, d, e} >= 0]]
```

> $\left\{\sqrt{a^2+b^2},\sqrt{b^2+c^2},\sqrt{c^2+d^2},\sqrt{d^2+e^2}\right\}$

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks!

Comment: @AaronEiben, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e};
```

Using `SequenceCases`

```
SequenceCases[list, x :{_, _} :> Norm[x], Overlaps -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Also: `SequenceCases[list, {a_, b_} :> Sqrt[a^2 + b^2], Overlaps -> True]`

Answer (score 1):

```
l = {a, b, c, d, e};
```

---

Using `FoldPairList`:

```
f = List /@ FoldPairList[TakeDrop, #, {2, 2}] & /@ {#, RotateLeft@#} &;

Simplify[Norm @@@ Riffle @@ f@l, Thread[l > 0]]
```

[image]

A simpler alternative that uses `FoldPairList` (Thanks to @Syed!):

```
FoldPairList[ {Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2], #2} &, list]
```

[image]

Comment: `FoldPairList[ {Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2], #2} &, list]`