# Fastest way : two by two list inversion

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

Consider a list of even length, for example `list={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}`

what is the fastest way to accomplish both these operations ?

**Operation 1**: two by two element inversion, the output is:

```
{2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7}
```

A code that work is:

```
Flatten@(Reverse@Partition[list,2])
```

**Operation 2**: Two by two Reverse, the output is:

```
{7,8,5,6,3,4,1,2}
```

A code that work is:

```
Flatten@(Reverse@Partition[Reverse[list],2])
```

**The real lists have length 16, no need for anything adapated to long lists**

Comment: You want that to be done for many lists at once?

Comment: Not necessarily, but I could tweak my code to make it so, so yes why not !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can achieve a speed up of approx. 2 by using `Riffle`:

list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

For the first problem:

```
Riffle[list[[2 ;; ;; 2]], list[[1 ;; ;; 2]]]
```

For the second problem:

```
Riffle[list[[-2 ;; 1 ;; -2]], list[[-1 ;; 2 ;; -2]]]
```

Answer (score 10):

If you have the do that very often, store your lists in a packed matrix like `a` below (that's a good idea anyways!), use your current code to generate a permutation, and then use `Part` to apply the permutations on the columns of `a`

```
n = 16;
a = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {1000000, n}];

p1 = Flatten@(Reverse@Partition[Range[n], 2]);
b1 = Map[Flatten@(Reverse@Partition[#, 2]) &, a]; // RepeatedTiming // First
c1 = a[[All, p1]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
b1 == c1

p2 = Flatten@(Reverse@Partition[Range[n, 1, -1], 2]);
b2 = Map[Flatten@(Reverse@Partition[Reverse[#], 2]) &, a]; // RepeatedTiming // First
c2 = a[[All, p2]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
b2 == c2
```

> 0.338
>
> 0.041
>
> True
>
> 0.463
>
> 0.040
>
> True

If you are still free to choose you data layout, then you may consider to store the lists in "structure of arrays" format (i.e., by using the transpose of `a`) in order to obtain a small percentage of extra performance:

```
aT = Transpose[a];
b1T = aT[[p1]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
b2T = aT[[p2]]; // RepeatedTiming // First

Transpose[b1] == b1T
Transpose[b2] == b2T
```

> 0.035
>
> 0.035
>
> True
>
> True

Answer (score 10):

```
PermutationList[Cycles[Partition[list,2]]]
```

> ```
> {2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7}
> ```

Simply `Reverse` the output above to get your second list:

```
Reverse @ %
```

> ```
> {7, 8, 5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2}
> ```

Alternatively, define a `Cycles` object that can used to `Permute` other lists:

```
cycles = Cycles[Partition[Range @ 8, 2]];

Permute[list, cycles]
```

> ```
> {2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7}
> ```

or

```
 list[[PermutationList @ cycles]]
```

> ```
> {2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7}
> ```

`Reverse` the input list and `Permute`:

```
Permute[Reverse @ list,cycles]
```

> ```
> {7, 8, 5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2}
> ```

```
Permute[CharacterRange["A", "H"], cycles]
```

> ```
> {"B", "A", "D", "C", "F", "E", "H", "G"}
> ```

```
Permute[Reverse @ CharacterRange["A", "H"], cycles]
```

> ```
> {"G", "H", "E", "F", "C", "D", "A", "B"}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

SequenceCases[list, x : {_, _} :> Splice @ Reverse @ x]
```

{2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7}

```
SequenceCases[Reverse @ list, x : {_, _} :> Splice @ Reverse @ x]
```

{7, 8, 5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2}

Answer (score 1):

Using `Developer PartitionMap` and `Reverse`:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

Reverse@Developer`PartitionMap[Sequence @@ Reverse @@ {#} &, list, 2]

(*{7, 8, 5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2}*)
```

Or, as @eldo points out, using `BlockMap`, as he also made use of `BlockMap` in the post-[Reference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4061/how-to-map-a-subset-of-list-elements-to-a-function/293966#293966):

```
Reverse@BlockMap[Sequence @@ Reverse@# &, list, 2]

(*{7, 8, 5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2}*)
```

Comment: Or `BlockMap` instead of `Developer...`

Comment: That's right, @eldo, I remember you used `BlockMap`. Let me quote you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Using `TakeList`:**

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}

sel = List /@ Flatten@Table[{2, 1}, Length@list/2];

TakeList[list, sel] // Flatten
```

> {2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7}